# Qual a diferença entre a JVM, JRE e JDK

Tags: java, jvm, jdk, jre

Eu andei pesquisando e ainda não entendi muito bem a diferença entre eles, principalmente entre o JRE e JDK.

A JVM seria como o coração do Java, e além disso eu ouvi dizer que ela "não existe fisicamente", como assim? Se ela não existe fisicamente o JRE e JDK existem "fisicamente"?

Por que ter o JRE se existe o JDK?

Qual a diferença entre a JVM, JRE e JDK?

E como um extra, essas siglas são masculinas ou femininas? Eu vejo diversas pessoas falando "a" JVM/JRE/JDK, e outras falando que o certo é "o". Afinal, qual está correto?

Comment: eu acho que essa pergunta até tem salvação se deixar mais objetiva. A parte do artigo nao ajuda (a nao ser como complemento, pq é um problema de tradução e não de programação),  e essas pressuposições de "existir fisicamente" não ajudam. Às vezes "menos é mais" quando se trata de objetividade. A parte das diferenças parece válida.

Comment: JDK é só o SDK do Java. Só traduzir o termo para o português que fica fácil saber se é masculino ou feminino. O resto não dá para saber sobre o que é.

Comment: As perguntas _linkadas_ não respondem a diferença entre JVM, JRE e JDK, apenas falam da JVM

Comment: Você não as leu então.

Comment: E quanto a parte do por que existe o JRE se tem o JDK?

Comment: Sabendo o que é cada um vê que a pergunta não faz sentido.

Comment: @NinjaTroll o JRE é para o usuário que não precisa das ferramentas de desenvolvedor, como o meu irmão que joga Minecraft, ou minha professora de banco de dados que só usa pra executar um programa de modelagem e faz todo o resto com PHP ou com o próprio cliente do PostgreSQL (o PgAdmin). Como nenhum deles usa, ou ao menos se interessa pela programação na linguagem, não existe necessidade de manter todas as ferramentas do JDK disponíveis

Comment: eu tava digitando o finalzinho das respostas e corrigindo as referências quando a pergunta foi fechada hehehehe